# Controller test for nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, for-loop, testing, ruby-on-rails-5

can't go over the problem with CREATING INDEX ROUTE TEST for nested attribute. I've been trying all my ideas but nothing works

I have Service model and ServiceRoute model.

**ServiceRoute belongs_to Service**

and

**Service has_many ServiceRoutes.**

Here is my controller:

```
class ServiceRoutesController < ApplicationController

before_action :set_service_route, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]
before_action :set_service, only: :create


def create
  @service_route = @service.service_routes.build(service_route_params)

  if @service_route.save
    render json: @service_route, status: :created, location: @service_route
  else
    render json: @service_route.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end


private

  def set_service_route
    @service_route = ServiceRoute.find(params[:id])
  end

  def set_service
   @service = Service.find(params[:service_id])
  end

  def service_route_params
    params.require(:service_route).permit(:routes_list, :service_id)
  end
end
```

**I create ServiceRoute with build method**

My routes.rb file:

```
resources :services do
  resources :service_routes
end
```

Test "should create service route" has an error:

**ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"service_routes"} missing required keys: [:service_id]**

```
test "should create service_route" do
 assert_difference('ServiceRoute.count') do
  post service_service_routes_url, params: { service_route: {routes_list: 
  @service_route.routes_list, service_id: @service_route.service_id } }, 
 as: :json
end
```

How should I refactor this test to match the route: **/services/:service_id/service_routes**

Comment: Try sending the `:service_id` param out of the `:service_route` key. It's easy to overlook things like this.

Comment: test "should create service_route" do 
      assert_difference('ServiceRoute.count') do
      post service_service_routes_url, params: { service_route: { 
      routes_list: @service_route.routes_list}, service_id: 
     @service_route.service_id  }, as: :json end

Comment: you mean like this? Unfortunatelly does not work :/

Comment: It's weird the test is trying to reach the `:index` action when you're clearly sending POST. Force `post :create` instead of sending the route.

Comment: Your solution with sending the :service_id param out of the :service_route key works for **service_routes_url** but please notice that I want to check **service_service_routes_url**

Comment: Is the subject of your test `ServiceRouteController` or `ServiceController`? It should be `ServiceRouteController` to use the `post :create` approach.

Comment: Might be looking in a wrong controller ...

Comment: I was thinking about it couple hours ago :) Thanks

Comment: Got it working? If so, I'll write a proper answer.

Comment: I don't know yet, I'll let you know

Comment: didn't work for  service_service_routes_url but for service_routes_url YES

Answer (score 1):

Testing nested routes may bring some confusion with regards to where the tests should be placed. Although nesting may give you the feeling the tests for the children should be written inside of the parent's tests, in fact they should be isolated in their own Test Case.

Rspec infers the controller being tested using the Test Case class name. You can also indicate it using a class method `.tests`.

> ActionController::TestCase will automatically infer the controller
>   under test from the test class name. If the controller cannot be
>   inferred from the test class name, you can explicitly set it with
>   +tests+.

Although you might be tempted to use the path as the first argument to the method `.post`, `TestCase` expects an action name such as `:index`, `:create`, `:update` and so on. The correct syntax for your test should be:

```
post :create, params: {
  service_id: @service_route.service_id,
  service_route: {
      routes_list: @service_route.routes_list 
    }
  }
```

Here's a snipet of the documentation for the `TestCase.get`.

```
  # Simulate a GET request with the given parameters.
  #
  # - +action+: The controller action to call.
  # - +params+: The hash with HTTP parameters that you want to pass. This may be +nil+.
  # - +body+: The request body with a string that is appropriately encoded
  #   (<tt>application/x-www-form-urlencoded</tt> or <tt>multipart/form-data</tt>).
  # - +session+: A hash of parameters to store in the session. This may be +nil+.
  # - +flash+: A hash of parameters to store in the flash. This may be +nil+.
  #
  # You can also simulate POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, and HEAD requests with
  # +post+, +patch+, +put+, +delete+, and +head+.
  # Example sending parameters, session and setting a flash message:
  #
  #   get :show,
  #     params: { id: 7 },
  #     session: { user_id: 1 },
  #     flash: { notice: 'This is flash message' }
```